# Low power, isolated, compact 230AC to 3.3DC power supply with very low heat dissipation?

Tags: power-supply, low-power, heat, efficiency, 3.3v

Need an *isolated, compact 230V AC to 3.3V DC power supply* with **very low heat dissipation.** No heating is extremely important as – unfortunately – this regulator will be placed enough close to a precision temperature sensor to possibly make trouble.

The power can be *well below 1W,* don't think the current needed will exceed 100…150 mA.

Anything ready-made isn't even remotely close to a 90% efficiency (which even might not be enough for me). So I have to do the circuit myself. Note that just **resistive losses** are important here, dont't care about other power leaks which don't generate heat. Isolation is also very important, so I cant't avoid a magnetic or a piezo transformer.

May I have some guidelines to make such a power supply? Will be directy mounted on the main PCB, together with the other components of the device.

Obviously simple, popular solutions like USB charger + 3.3V LDO are completely out of question.

UPDATE: The device will be a smart thermostat terminal, mounted directly in the wall, that is, precision thermometer + display and WiFi capable MCU in a rotary knob. All the power-hungry parts reside in the knob, well outside the wall, but the source still have to stay in the box, in the wall.

[image: Wall WiFi Thermostat]

Comment: How compact is compact?  What is the maximum acceptable heat generated?  What is your power requirement?  "Well below 1W" and less than 100 and 150 mA isn't precise enough. I feel like this is a bit of an XY problem and you might be able to fix this a different way; why does the power supply have to be mounted so close to the sensor?

Comment: You mention `precision`, which is a good choice of wording as you didn't use `accuracy`. You may need to calibrate out `systematic error` to get accuracy, if that's a goal. (It may not be.) But whether or not you need accuracy, if you can ensure that the resistive losses are fixed rather than varying, you may be able to account for the systematic error caused by those resistive losses. Clearly, that only works if it is stable and unvarying. But it may be another thing to consider in the design process. You might shoot for low and consistent accountable losses rather than very, very low losses.

Comment: What is the application? Remote temperature sensor with radio transmission over wifi, zigbee, etc?

Comment: @periblepsis a heating source near a temparature sensor is not a typical systematic error which you can calibrate back efficiently. But even if you could I think it's still a really resasonable requirement to keep heat dissipation as low as it's possible near a temperature sensor.

Comment: @bobflux yes, a smart thermostat unit which actually just measures the temperature, displays/inputs the values and sends information over wifi to a server which does the rest (PID heating control etc).

Comment: @vir, well, better not to exceed 30×30×18 mm. Have no clue yet about the maximum acceptable heat as it's impossible to modelling in this early stage. Thel lower the better. The nominal consumption will be even below 50 mA,, with possible short peaks up to 150 mA, but this is again just an approximation. And no, I cannot place the power supply elsewhere as I have no injection molding machine and should be happy with the ready-made case I already have.

Comment: @ZoltánBíró I don't disagree. I am only suggesting a way of widening the thought processes to include more within its sweep. If you have already discounted the idea, that's fine. I just wanted to make sure you put some thought to it and removed it. That's all.

Comment: ALL power consumption ends up as heat. If your circuit consumes 50 mA (150 peak) at 3.3 V, that's 165 mW (500 peak) of heat that gets dissipated inside your little box. If your power supply is, say, 80% efficient, then that rises to 200 mW (600 peak), which is hardly significant in comparison. You might be radiating some amount of power away as radio waves (and I would assume that's during the peak consumption), but even that is insignificant.

Comment: @DaveTweed, Please! Please! Trust me. 
The 165 mW WON'T DISSIPATE INSIDE MY LITTLE BOX. As it happens, the power hungry elements, like the MCU and the display all are OUTSIDE the box, in a rotary knob. Just the supply will be inside the box. 
I asked a specific question: how to design a source optimised for low heat dissipation. And instead of helping me everybody kept trying to convince me that my question was irrelevant. What if just trusted me that I knew what I wanted?

Comment: @ZoltánBíró But what if you have an XY problem, maybe you want something that can be better solved in another way? Like having the supply or regulation further away and just sense and regulate the voltage remotely?

Comment: @Justme This will be the cheaper version, that is, the device will have direct 3.3V inputs as well. But as lots of customers still want to get supplied the device out-the-box, from the L and N wires already available in the mounting box, I also have to take in account the embedded power supply version for some (maybe more expensive) models.

Comment: The question is not written in a way that engenders that kind of trust. There are very few actual numerical requirements, it doesn't list all of the physical constraints, and it uses terminology in non-standard ways that make it sound like you don't know what you're talking about. If you had written it with all of the details that you're now putting into comments, you would have gotten a much more direct answer.

Comment: And anyway, how is a "precision temperature sensor" supposed to work inside a box inside a wall with a power supply, and a heat-dissipating control knob between it and the room air it is supposedly sensing?!? You need to demonstrate a reasonable thermal model of this system before it makes sense to discuss the electrical details.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I asked for one thing, how to optimise a small, low power  230→3V3 supply for minimal heat dissipation. If I tried to explain in detail how I placed the sensor to get most  of precision, where I should place the supply and why I've choosen this variant etc. it would have consumed tens of thousands of characters and nobody has been read it. (By the way: the sensor is OUTSIDE the box as weell, as you can see on the rendering. But still not that good if there is a heat generator at a distance of just 3-4 cm from it) Really don't understand why you don't trust that I know what i do?!

Comment: Chalk it up to language issues, then. You may think you've explained all of those things clearly, but it isn't coming across that way. If that's the one thing you want to know, then you need to make the requirement specific: Exactly how many mW of heat from the power supply can you tolerate before you lose the precision you want in your sensor? And don't forget that we're all volunteers here. We need to *believe* that your requirement is realistic before we're going to put the effort into solving it for you. So err on the side of more information rather than less in order to convince us.

Comment: @DaveTweed, you cannot be serious about asking me to tell you, how many mW of heat can kill the sensor precision. This can be found either just after weeks of heavy computer modelling or by building the prototype (with huge waste of parts and materials), and seeing what happens. Isn't much simpler to think forward and find by start the lowest possible heat dissipation supply – obviously in limits of reasonable costs and size – to build the prototype directly? And, in the worst case, I'll know what would be the achiewable precision WHEN SUPPLYING FROM AC (as 3.3V models will also be available).

Answer (score 1):

In your case of wifi temperature sensor with display, if you use the micro's sleep mode, wifi sleep and transmit only when needed (every couple seconds, not 10 times per second) you can expect average power use to be very low (say 5-10mA maximum) with large peaks corresponding to WiFi transmission. Here's an [example](https://blog.voneicken.com/2018/lp-wifi-esp32-pushed/) with about 5mA average. LCD and buttons use close to zero power.

Of course if you want it to have ping response time of 1ms that is not compatible with wifi power saving.

Since that is an average power consumption of less than 20mW, the largest consumer in your device is likely to be the AC-DC switching supply's idle power.

You can profile the micro's power consumption like so:

- x% of the time in sleep mode, using µA
- y% of the time running the CPU but not WiFi, using mA
- z% of the time using WiFi, using hundreds of mA

With a standard AC-DC switching converter, the first two are basically the same and come down to its idle power dissipation. Only in the last case is the AC-DC converter's efficiency relevant.

So the total power use would be:

(AC-DC idle power) + z% * (power on 3V3 when using WiFi)/(AC-DC efficiency)

After profiling your power use you may find what happens to total power use with a difference between 75% and 85% efficiency in the AC-DC converter. Otherwise it is pointless to talk about efficiency.

To avoid a 5V to 3V3 LDO, the AC-DC supply should output 3V3 directly.

Now there are plenty of little PCB mount AC-DC bricks on the market. Most of them tend to be a bit large for your application. Here's [an example](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Powerline_AC-DC/RAC05-K.pdf) with decent efficiency (>75%), very low idle power (75mW), and small size.

In low output voltage AC-DC converters the output rectification diodes make up for a large part of the losses. The solution is to use synchronous rectification, but at this power level it is definitely not worth it.

Because hot air rises, a simple solution would be to add a few ventilation holes, and place the temperature sensor on the bottom of the device so it gets a fresh supply of air.

Comment: Well, (1) for WiFi I'll implement even a smarter thing, as ESP-NOW is able to transmit/receive small packets without logging in the WiFi network, and the smart server (where heating is irrelevant) will do the rest, (2) obviously the sensor will be placed on the bottom, but good ventillation in the box is still a problem, and (3) the biggest issue is that even if I leave ESP32-C3 sleep most of the time, the high resolution AMOLED display will be always on which might mean tens of milliampers, even on moderate brightess and dark color scheme (not the one you can see on the rendering).

Comment: So, As I understand, on low voltages like 3.3V the diodes are the most responsible of heat generating, that's why the lower the voltage, the worse the efficiency. But since there are reverse polarity protection circuits using MOSFETs (instead of bipolar diodes) which have just a few mV voltage drop can't understand how this idea can't be applied for high efficiency power supplies.

Comment: Higher power SMPS can do synchronous rectification with MOSFETs instead of diodes which gains some efficiency, but it costs extra. On a 200W power supply it's definitely worth it, but on a 3W power supply no-one is going to care.

Comment: I bet if you put the temperature sensor behind the square plate, away from the knob where the dissipation occurs, it'll be fine. You can always put some squishy thermal material between it and the plastic plate to get better thermal coupling. If the display is always on, then this is no good for a bedroom.

Comment: Spend more thoughts about where and especially *how* to mount and encapsulate the sensor. And spend less thoughts about that PSU.

Comment: @tobalt It seems that nobody have checked the rendering where the sensor position is clearly visible: the lower right corner of the square plate. If you have a better idea let me know.

Comment: Looks good. Its coupled well to the room. Put some foam on the backside between it and the electronics and it'll be fine